# AJAX, SEO and PHP folder trouble

Tags: php, ajax, seo, directory

I'm creating an AJAX script that reads a specific file, which name is identified with a GET var. The beginning of the script in `index.php` is:

```
var expFile = '<?php echo $_GET['text_name']; ?>';
$(document).ready(function () {

$.ajax({
    url: expFile+'.xml',
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'xml',
    success: function (data, textStatus) {

    // Parses the content, which is escaped into a "text" tag in the xml, and puts it
    //into an html div with a "content" class"

        var content = decodeURIComponent($(data).find('text').text());
        $('.content').html(content);
    }
});
});
```

And everything went ok. The file is read and the thing is shown correctly.
The XML file, that is in the same folder of the index.php file, is read directly from AJAX.

Now i'm using a mod_rewrite in order to make the URL SEO-Friendly.
When i type the dirty URL (`http://www.mysite.com/index.php?text_name=name-of-the-file-to-read`) it's OK.

**But when i type the rewritten url** (which is `http://www.mysite.com/lyrics/name-of-the-file-to-read`) the content is not shown.

I know that AJAX is client-side, while mod_rewrite is server-side, but I don't know how to reach a parent folder (that really doesn't exist)  from the "url" parameter of the `$.ajax`  or an absolute link like `url: 'http://...'` (but it goes against Same Origin Policy).

Help me please!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Francesco's answer, initially put into the question:*

SOLVED.

THE PROBLEM was with the script tag. I had to put a `../` to the jquery href

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../libraries/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Then I added `../` to the URL and everything went fine.

Answer (score 0):

The URL is having `.xml` appended by the function itself - on this line:

```
url: expFile+'.xml',
```

Is that still there when you are trying with the SEO friendly URL? If so, I'd remove that appended `.xml` and try again.

Comment: the seo friendly url is without .xml in the end. i did a mistake while writing the post: the GET var is without .xml

Comment: the problem is not the syntax or file names, but the fact that the file, when using SEO, is not found. I think that the problem is the "lyrics/" folder: probably AJAX thinks that this is a folder, so I have to browse in the root folder and find the xml file... but how can  I do it with AJAX? I tried with "../"+expFile+".xml", but nothing happens. I also tried with the absolute web path, "http://www.mysite.com/"+expFile+".xml", but it doesn't work.